# How to redirect users after login based on wp user meta key?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I'm having a problem with this redirect after login. I added an extra field in the registration, then after that. If a user logins, I want to redirect that person to the specified URL based on the EXTRA FIELD he/she entered.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you're using `update_usermeta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );`, the following will do.

I created a [custom profile field](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields) named `twitter` and applied this hook to `wp_login`:

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'redirect_login_so_21774306', 10, 2 );

function redirect_login_so_21774306( $user_login, $user )
{
    $twitter = get_the_author_meta( 'twitter', $user->data->ID );
    if( $twitter )
    {
        wp_redirect( site_url( "custom-post/?twitter=$twitter", 'http' ), 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
```